# Ios - Facebook login - Facebook browser in app connexion not working

Tags: facebook, meteor

I’m using Meteor 1.6.1 and using Facebook Login.

Facebook Login is working perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Facebook browser Android, Mac but it’s not working on Facebook in app browser ios.

The popup message never disappears:
Login completed. click here to close this window

This behavior only happens on the Facebook browser on ios.

How reproduce the error:

1- Share the url https://app.lovlyapp.com/ on your timeline
2 - Open the link on your ios facebook app
3 - Connect to the plateform (and you will see the error message).

Could you please help us solve this issue?

Thanks,

Olivier